# How to loop around and build an IP Address

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ip-address

Given 1.1.%.%, where % is a wildcard, I want to loop through all possible IP addresses.

So far I have been able to replace one % successfully with a loop, but when I attempt to try to replace 2, it simply replaces it with the same number. The following is the code I have at the moment, any help on how to put in this second loop to get the second % would be appreciated.

Code:

```
var wildCount = inputSt.match(/\%/g)  //works out how many % are there
var newPlaceholder ='' 
for (var i = 0; i < wildCount.length; i++){
    newPlaceHolder =inputSt.split("%").join(i)
    for (var n = 0; n <=254; n++){
        newPlaceholder = inputSt.split("%").join(n)
     }
 }
```

Output from this is 1.1.0.0, then 1.1.1.1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version of an anser uses recursion to perform the IP creations.  It splits on the decimals, and then recursively goes through the tokens to see if they are % or not, and if they are will interchange them for [0, tokenLimit] until it exhausts all possibilities.

For the sake of not blowing up the browser, I set the tokenLimit to 11, rather than 255.  Comments have been added to the logic for detailed explanations.

```js
var test = '1.1.%.%';
var tokens = test.split( '.' );
var tokenLimit = 11;

// start the recursion loop on the first token, starting with replacement value 0
makeIP( tokens, 0, 0 );

function makeIP ( tokens, index, nextValue ) {
  // if the index has not advanced past the last token, we need to
  // evaluate if it should change
  if ( index < tokens.length ) {
    // if the token is % we need to replace it
    if ( tokens[ index ] === '%' ) {
      // while the nextValue is less than our max, we want to keep making ips
      while ( nextValue < tokenLimit ) {
        // slice the tokens array to get a new array that will not change the original
        let newTokens = tokens.slice( 0 );
        // change the token to a real value
        newTokens[ index ] = nextValue++;
        
        // move on to the next token
        makeIP( newTokens, index + 1, 0 );
      }
    } else {
      // the token was not %, move on to the next token
      makeIP( tokens, index + 1, 0 );
    }
  } else {
    // the index has advanced past the last token, print out the ip
    console.log( tokens.join( '.' ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Take note that the console log that stack overflow makes visible appears to not show all the logs.  Look at your actual browser console when you run this.

Answer (score 1):

So, you don't want to increment by splitting on the '%' character. It'd be better to split by octet:

```
var octets = inputSt.split('.');
```

There you have octets 0-3 (since it's an array). You can then do a recursive if statement checking for the wildcard and increment as you go.

```
for (var i = 0; i < octets.length; i++) {
   if (octets[i].match('%')) {
      Do some incrementing...
   }
}
```

Obviously, this code isn't finished. But it should get you headed in the right direction.

*hint* - You want to support 1-4 wildcards. So it's probably best to create a function that increments a single octet. If the octet is not the last one with a wildcard, you call the same function again. Meat of that function is below. I'll let you figure out where and how to perform the individual incrementing.:

```
function incrementOctet(octet) {
   if (octet < 3) {
      if (octets[octet + 1].match('%')) {
         incrementOctet(octet + 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! For several reasons I'm actually only letting users use 2 wildcards in their input, mainly because of the amount of data they would match.